# How iis distinguish between mvc request and asp.netpage request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, request

How does IIS distinguish between an asp.net mvc request or a normal asp.net page request and how does it process the two different requests?

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The routing (generally configured in the global.asax) configures URLs to be handled by controllers/actions instead of actual aspx pages.

If the url doesn't match a route, it will try and find an actual file instead of an action.

Comment: Thanks for your response.But the global.asax file is associated with application,how iis will came to know that it's what type of request.